# SQL - Convert NULL to string.empty

Tags: sql

I'm trying to perform some upgrade maintenance on our database. I need to move 3 columns of data from all rows of one table and insert that data as new rows in a new table.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SnmpSettings]([NetworkDiscoveryId], [RoCommunities], [RwCommunities])
    SELECT id, Ro_Community, RW_Communities
    FROM [dbo].[Network_Discovery]
```

The above code would work fine, but Ro_Community and RW_Communities allow NULL where as RoCommunities and RwCommunities do not allow NULL. How should I convert NULLs to the empty string and then insert into my new table?

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SnmpSettings]([NetworkDiscoveryId], [RoCommunities], [RwCommunities])
    SELECT id, Ro_Community, RW_Communities
    ISNULL(Ro_Community,'')
    FROM [dbo].[Network_Discovery] 


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'Ro_Community'.
```

Comment: If it is Sql Server, use [isnull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)(Ro_Community, '')

Comment: I apologize for how naive I am in this bit of work. I've edited in my attempt to follow your instruction, but it does not compile.

Comment: `SELECT id, isnull(Ro_Community, ''), isnull(RW_Communities, '')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(Ro_Community, '')
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(Ro_Community, '')
```

Note: `COALESCE` is supported since SQL Server 2005. It is part of the ANSI-92 SQL standard, so many suggest it's preferred over `ISNULL`. However there are also reports that it is [a bit slower](http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/performance-coalesce-null/).

Comment: `ISNULL` *was* way faster for me.

Comment: @TotZam That's what I said, COALESCE is said to be slower